# Search complete phrases or words in array of NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, search, match, nspredicate

I am trying to find the way for searching whole phrases or words in an array. But it does not work. Eg.:

I have an `NSMutableArray` with 2 elements:
element 1 has a key desc: "example of an another element for this"
element 2 has a key desc: "example of another element for this other"

I want to search the elements containing the word "other" only.

If I use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"desc like '*other*'"];
```

results includes both elements.

If I search like "* other *" I will miss descriptions starting with "other" (because of the blanc).

Does anybody know a function to search exact words or phrases, in spite of being at the beginning, end, middle of the text and in spite of having a "." or a "," or a "'"?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a full regular expression match, `matches` provides this. Try (untested):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"desc matches '\\bother\\b'"];
```

The r.e. `\b` matches a word-boundary (double backslash above as it is an escape character in Objective-C and regular expressions...). See [Apple's docs for matches](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) and follow the link to the ICU regular expression guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regular pattern match will work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"desc matches %@", @".*\\bother\\b.*"];
```